# bitwise operation xor mask

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question I'm just having trouble understanding bits and bitwise operation assignment

I have two integers one is a mask and the other is arbitrary and I'm supposed to xor the integer with the 16 most significant bits of the mask but I'm not exactly sure if significant is the first 16 or the last 16 and if my operation is even correct since I don't know how to verify it
I tried this

```
int main(){
    uint32_t mask = 3405705229;
    uint16_t arbitrary = 0xABCD;

    arbitrary^=mask&16;
    printf("%X\n",arbitrary);
}
```

I assumed mask&16 would give me only the first 16 bits of mask
But when I print I still get ABCD so that can't be right..
I also tried `arbitrary^=(mask>>16)&16;` but that didn't do anything either

Comment: "Most significant" means the leftmost ones. `& 16` doesn't look right, you want `& 0xFFFF` (preceded by `>> 16`, otherwise you get least significant 16 bits).

Comment: So `arbitrary^=(mask>>16)&0xFFFF;` but wouldn't &16 mean its operating on 16 bits?

Comment: Yep, this looks ok. `& 16` would interpret 16 as binary (`1000`), and bitwise-and it with the number.

Comment: If a number is 1234 and you change the first digit from 1 to 2 (making 2234), how much does the number change by? If you change the last digit from 4 to 5 (making 1235), how much does the number change by? Which of those do you think is more significant?

Comment: Oh! I see so what you're doing is shifting it to the right by 16 bits and nullifying those bits by & it with 0xFFFF?

Comment: Well you can even use `arbitrary ^= mask >> 16`. There are no additional bits to get rid of. Even if there were, the fact that `arbitrary` is a 16bit variable would get rid those additional bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Mhm, I said `& 16` is wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ah, your “Yep, this looks ok.” was referring to a comment, not the question.

Comment: The only stupid question is the one that finnally ends not being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an unsigned 8-bit value, you might have:

```
Bit number:    7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
Bit value:     1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   = 141 = 0x8D
```

The 4 most significant bits (MSB) are bits 7-4; the 4 least significant bits (LSB) are bits 3-0.

You'd extract the 4 most significant bits from `uint8_t x8 = 141;` using:

```
uint8_t y = (x >> 4) & 0xF
```

The output would be `y` equal to 8 or `0x08`.

You can, of course, expand this to accommodate larger numbers of bits.

Note that MSB and LSB are often used for {Most|Least} Significant *Bytes* rather than *bits* — but that still applies in a similar way to the logical value in chunks of 8-bit bytes.  As [paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421195/paulsm4) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733043/bitwise-operation-xor-mask/70733123?noredirect=1#comment125044944_70733123) in a comment, this applies to the logical value.  CPUs come in two main flavours: big-endian (SPARC, older PowerPC, Motorola, …) and little-endian (Intel and many other chips, including modern PowerPC at least as an option).  The difference is the order in which the bytes of a multi-byte (integer) value are stored:

For a 4-byte unsigned integer with the value 0x12345678, the two types store the data in opposite orders:

Address         0x1000  0x1001  0x1002  0x1003
Big-Endian        0x12    0x34    0x56    0x78
Little-Endian     0x78    0x56    0x34    0x12

Big-Endian         MSB     ...     ...     LSB
Little-Endian      LSB     ...     ...     MSB

These days, little-endian is more widespread.  However, many network protocols and other systems mandate big-endian.  Most of the time, you don't have to worry about it.  Sometimes, you do — and it is important to know when you do and when you don't.  Data on a single machine, not shared elsewhere, usually doesn't require you to worry about byte order.  You don't have to worry about the byte order of data in (single-byte) character strings.

Comment: So most significant is the left most bits and least significant is the right most bits

Comment: Yes — that's correct.

Comment: So would &0xF be even necessary in this case since once x is shifted the four left bits are just left at 00?

Comment: This is a good answer.  One additional consideration to be aware of: [byte ordering (Endianness)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  LSB and MSB is the *logical bit* ordering.  Different CPUs (an Intel 808x vs. a SPARC RISC) might have different *physical byte* ordering.  This is especially important to remember when you're transferring binary data between hosts.

Comment: @Kayla — With the 8-bit unsigned values, the `& 0x0F` masking operation isn't really necessary; with larger numbers of bits, the masking can be necessary.  For example, if you want bits 7-3 of a 16-bit number, you need `(bits16 >> 4) & 0x0F` to get just those 4 bits without interference from what's in the 8 most significant bits of the `bits16` value.

Answer (score 1):

In a binary number, the bit furthest to the left is called the most significant bit (msb) and the bit furthest to the right is called the least significant bit (lsb). if someone says to mask with 16 most significant bits then you should try to get the 16 bits from left to right.

you can get the most significant 16 bits with the help of left shift operator.

Left shift operators shift the number to the left and fill the most significant bits by zero(you should not use left shift operator with negative numbers).

so following line will do the job.

```
arbitrary^=(mask>>16);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not exactly sure if significant is the first 16 or the last 16 and if my operation is even correct since I don't know how to verify it I tried this

A simple way to verify is to change your data into some easy to guess numbers.

Just try with mask == 1, which will make an even number into the next odd number or a positive odd number into the previous even one.

Answer (score 0):

The most significant bits are the highest bits (from the left). Since the mask is 32 bits, you just have to shift the left 16 bits to cover the right 16 bits. The space on the left will be filled with zeroes.
Then you can use this mask with your 16 bit number.

```
int main(){
    uint32_t mask = 3405705229;
    uint16_t arbitrary = 0xABCD;

    arbitrary^ = (mask>>16);
    printf("%X\n",arbitrary);
}
```

output: 6133

btw, the mask value is a joke right? In hex it's value is CAFEF00D.
(you should also try uint16_t arbitrary = 0x1453;)